# Finding the maximum volume of a cuboid in a sphere

Tags: calculus, geometry, optimization

A cuboid, length of whose one edge is √2 units, is inscribed in a sphere of radius of √2 units. If maximum possible volume of suboid is V cubic units, then V/2√2 is

I took the equation of sphere to be x^2 +y^2 +z^2 =2 but I'm confused on how to express the volume of cuboid in terms of x, y and z because after that I could just differentiate with respect of x, y and z and maybe it would simplify

Comment: I honestly don't think coordinates is the way to go here. I see no reason it won't ultimately give you the correct answer, but I think coordinate-free geometry is easier in this case.

Comment: The cuboid will have vertices at $(\pm x,\pm y, \pm \sqrt{2}/2)$, so the side lengths are $2x,2y,\sqrt{2}$ and the volume is proportional to $4\sqrt{2} xy$.

Comment: Setting one edge of the cuboid effectively fixes its size. What am I missing?

Comment: Welcome to math.SE! [Here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/)'s a tutorial and reference for typesetting math on this site. Also, the title (which refers to a cube) doesn’t match the question (which refers to a cuboid).

Answer (score 0):

It is easier to work with the halves of the edges, so we have p, q, and $ \frac {\sqrt 2}{2} $, so the volume is $ 4 \sqrt 2 p q$.
To maximize the volume, we can ignore the coefficient and just maximize pq.
We have that, being inscribed, $ \frac {1}{2} + p^2 + q^2 = 2 $, so $ q = \sqrt {\frac {3}{2} - p^2} $

Maximizing $ p \sqrt {\frac {3}{2} - p^2} $ means finding the zero for the derivative, and, after some rewriting, $ \sqrt {\frac {3}{2} - p^2} - \frac {p^2} { \sqrt {\frac {3}{2} - p^2} } = 0 $,
or $ 2 p^2 = \frac {3}{2} $ or $ p = \frac { \sqrt 3}{2} $, so we have the more or less expected result that the maximum is reached for $ p = q = \frac { \sqrt 3}{2} $, so the edges are $ \sqrt 2 , \sqrt 3 $ and  $ \sqrt 3 $ and the total maximal volume of the cuboid $ 3 \sqrt 2 $.

Comment: A non mathjaxed question is no excuse to write a non mathjaxed answer. Reach out to OP to fix that please, and fix your answer.